# Avoid losing focus while dragging over iframe

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following HTML with 2 columns of content while a resizer-column is in the middle. With the drag indicator I´m able to change the relative width of those columns.
This works well unless an iframe is in the content of column named "after". When dragging the indicator very speedy to the right, it hovers over the iframe and looses focus, then the effect stops working...

```
<div class="before">some Content</div>
<div id="resizeable" class="resizer" resize-two-columns-width-slider><md-icon>drag_indicator</md-icon></div>
<div class="after">!!! this does not work when an iframe is inserted here !!!</div>
```

This is the directive I use in AngularJS:

```
module.directive("resizeTwoColumnsWidthSlider", () => {
    var directive = {
        link: onResizeTwoColumnsWidth,
        restrict: 'AE'
    };
    return directive;

    function onResizeTwoColumnsWidth(scope, element, attrs) {

        var m_pos;
        var resizer = element[0];

        function mouseupfunc() {
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
            document.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseupfunc, false);
            saveDocsViewColumnWidths();
        }

        resizer.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            m_pos = e.x;
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseupfunc, false);
        }, false);

        function resize(e) {
            var before = resizer.parentNode.firstElementChild;
            var after = resizer.parentNode.lastElementChild;
            var dx = m_pos - e.x;
            m_pos = e.x;
            var beforeWidth = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(before, '').width) - dx) + "px";
            var afterWidth = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(after, '').width) + dx) + "px";
            before.style.width = beforeWidth;
            after.style.width = afterWidth;
            before.style.minWidth = "525px";
            after.style.minWidth = "415px";
        }
    }
});

I uncommented the touch-area for mobile devices - there it works without problems on the iframe...Thx
```